# Assembly x86 Value isn't copying correctly?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
;-57,319,865
mov eax, [dNum5]
mov edx, [dNum6]
imul edx
;mov [message], eax
mov [qAns14], eax
```

The answer should be -57,319,865 as noted in the comment. Whenever I look at the message variable I created, it's correct. When I look at qAns14, it's 4,237,647,431 . I have no idea why - I declared both variables like this:

```
message     dq  0
qAns14      dq  0
```

I can't even imagine why moving eax to message gives a correct result yet moving it to qAns14 doesn't. Any insight? Thanks!

EDIT:

I found that doing this gives the correct answer:

```
mov eax, [dNum5]
mov edx, [dNum6]
imul edx
mov [qAns14], eax
mov [qAns14+4], edx
```

I needed to add the higher portion as suggested by Peter Counts. It simply never occurred to me since I could see the correct answer when moving it to the message variable - what's the explanation for that?? I think one of the comments answers it but the explanation went over my head.

EDIT:

I see now that the reason for it were the commands used to display the variables:

```
echo qAns14: \t
x/dg &qAns14
echo MESSAGE: \t
x/dw &message
```

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: It's also because they're effectively truncating the 64-bit EDX:EAX result to 32-bit, and zero-extending it by storing only the low half dword into a `dq 0` qword where the high half is already zero.  So I think they're actually printing a signed 64-bit value, but forgot to store the high half of the `imul` result.

Comment: You're printing the message as a GDB signed "word" (32-bit), aka an x86 dword.  But `qAns14` as a GDB "giant" (64-bit), including the high zeros.